# Respond to apple tv controls during video playback

Tags: ios, controls, tvos, apple-tv

I have an app with a AVPlayer to play video. I would like to be able to detect when the user has pressed a button on the remote control. I have tried implementing the following methods, however the remoteControlReceivedWithEvent() doesn't respond to any control events.

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay) {
            NSLog(@"play");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) {
            NSLog(@"pause");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause) {
            NSLog(@"toggle");
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Setup Apple TV control events
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Remove Apple TV control events
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with projects built using Xcode 7/iOS 9 SDK. Tried the same thing using Xcode 6, works perfectly. 
I have raised it with Apple bug reporter.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot detect this via remote control events, the events listed in your code can be detected by monitoring the playback rate of the player.

If using AVPlayer, add a KVO listener for 'rate'. When this changes to 0.0 the playback has been paused, and when it changes to 1.0, it is playing again.

I've used this successfully to update my UI controls to reflect the current state.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have already implemented this. However, it is possible to detect remote control events (as in the above code), Apple dev support have confirmed this. This works in apps built using iOS 8 SDK and below, iOS 9 SDK has broken this. Apple is working on a fix.

Comment: I hope you're right. I tried to get this to work for ages, and it still doesn't in my code, despite it being almost identical to the above example. Also, lots of other people believe that only control centre events are working, not the remote. Still, if what you say is correct, maybe there is another reason it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You use UITapGestureRecognizer to detect button clicks on tvOS. Set the allowedPressType property (e.g. to @[@(UIPressTypePlayPause)]).

However, you should not implement custom interactive playback UIs on tvOS. Instead, use AVPlayerViewController (AVKit). Your custom player will fall substantially short of user expectations (Siri commands won't work, some remotes won't work, your gestures will be slightly different, etc).

If you found AVPlayerViewController too limiting on other platforms, take another look—there are a number of new APIs on tvOS for enhanced playback, including external metadata and interstitials.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response, however this is not a tvOS related question. I am just referring to normal airplay on an Apple TV (1st, 2nd or 3rd Gen).

Comment: Is the remote paired with your AirPlay-ing machine (OS X or iOS)?

Comment: Pairing is not necessary on Apple TV. The remotes work regardless.